# PHP Remove JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to remove JavaScript from the HTML.

I can't get the regular expression to work with PHP; it's giving me an null array.  Why?

```
<?php
$var = '
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function selectCode(a) 
{ 
   var e = a.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName(PRE)[0]; 
   if (window.getSelection) 
   { 
      var s = window.getSelection(); 
       if (s.setBaseAndExtent) 
      { 
         s.setBaseAndExtent(e, 0, e, e.innerText.length - 1); 
      } 
      else 
      { 
         var r = document.createRange(); 
         r.selectNodeContents(e); 
         s.removeAllRanges(); 
         s.addRange(r); 
      } 
   } 
   else if (document.getSelection) 
   { 
      var s = document.getSelection(); 
      var r = document.createRange(); 
      r.selectNodeContents(e); 
      s.removeAllRanges(); 
      s.addRange(r); 
   } 
   else if (document.selection) 
   { 
      var r = document.body.createTextRange(); 
      r.moveToElementText(e); 
      r.select(); 
   } 
} 
</script>
';

   function remove_javascript($java){
   echo preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/i', "", $java);

   }    
?>
```

Comment: I think better use some proper libraries to kill those <script tags, a regex cannot cover all those, an example, `<scr/***/ipt> EVIL_CODES </scr/*                */ipt>`

Comment: not working getting the same thing

Comment: If you are trying to prevent XSS, I think you should read this page http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html before you try something useless. There are a lot of methods to inject scripts.

Comment: @Arkh is absolutely right.  I don't know if this was meant to provide some level of XSS safety but it doesn't.  Consider the trivial input `<scrip<script></script>t>alert(1337)</script>`.  It matches the inner empty script tag, but removing that leaves a new script tag intact.  To say nothing of scripts in URLs, event handlers, CSS, etc.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

this should do it:

```
echo preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $var);
```

/s is so that the dot . matches newlines too.

Just a warning, you should not use this type of regexp to sanitize user input for a website. There is just too many ways to get around it. For sanitizing use something like the http://htmlpurifier.org/ library

Comment: I think this does not cover the case mentioned before, <scr/* */ipt> 
which is exactly what someone who tried to bypass such a check would do.

Comment: Will a browser really run something inside `<scr/* */ipt>`? I find that hard to believe...

Comment: I have changed/improved it slightly (especially to match any optional whitespace in the tag, which browsers would ignore, too): 
`$html = preg_replace('~<\s*\bscript\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*script\s*>~is', '', $html);`

Comment: hey gnude, when they update the database to strip out all comments, yes, yes it will... lol. :)

Comment: Don't forget the easy workaround `<img src="nonexistent" onerror="evil()">`. Removing only script tags will still leave you vulnerable to injected javascript

Comment: if your document has many `<script>` tags, `?` is the key - Lazy quantifier `Matches as few characters as possible.`

Answer (score 4):

This might do more than you want, but depending on your situation you might want to look at [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip%20tags).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea

```
while (true) {
  if ($beginning = strpos($var,"<script")) {
    $stringLength = (strpos($var,"</script>") + strlen("</script>")) - $beginning;
    substr_replace($var, "", $beginning, $stringLength);
  } else {
    break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you could regard the string as a list of newline delimited strings and remove the lines containing the script tags(first & second to last) and you wouldn't even need regular expressions.

Though if what you are trying to do is preventing [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) it might not be sufficient to only remove script tags.

Comment: well thanks for the advice however what i am doing is creating an ripper so that was needed in my class code thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
function clean_jscode($script_str) {
    $script_str = htmlspecialchars_decode($script_str);
    $search_arr = array('<script', '</script>');
    $script_str = str_ireplace($search_arr, $search_arr, $script_str);
    $split_arr = explode('<script', $script_str);
    $remove_jscode_arr = array();
    foreach($split_arr as $key => $val) {
        $newarr = explode('</script>', $split_arr[$key]);
        $remove_jscode_arr[] = ($key == 0) ? $newarr[0] : $newarr[1];
    }
    return implode('', $remove_jscode_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any JavaScript code from HTML string with the help of following PHP function

You can read more about it here:
https://mradeveloper.com/blog/remove-javascript-from-html-with-php

```
function sanitizeInput($inputP)
{
    $spaceDelimiter = "#BLANKSPACE#";
    $newLineDelimiter = "#NEWLNE#";
                                
    $inputArray = [];
    $minifiedSanitized = '';
    $unMinifiedSanitized = '';
    $sanitizedInput = [];
    $returnData = [];
    $returnType = "string";

    if($inputP === null) return null;
    if($inputP === false) return false;
    if(is_array($inputP) && sizeof($inputP) <= 0) return [];

    if(is_array($inputP))
    {
        $inputArray = $inputP;
        $returnType = "array";
    }
    else
    {
        $inputArray[] = $inputP;
        $returnType = "string";
    }

    foreach($inputArray as $input)
    {
        $minified = str_replace(" ",$spaceDelimiter,$input);
        $minified = str_replace("\n",$newLineDelimiter,$minified);

        //removing <script> tags
        $minifiedSanitized = preg_replace("/[<][^<]*script.*[>].*[<].*[\/].*script*[>]/i","",$minified);

        $unMinifiedSanitized = str_replace($spaceDelimiter," ",$minifiedSanitized);
        $unMinifiedSanitized = str_replace($newLineDelimiter,"\n",$unMinifiedSanitized);

        //removing inline js events
        $unMinifiedSanitized = preg_replace("/([ ]on[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}=\".*\")|([ ]on[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}='.*')|([ ]on[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}=.*[.].*)/","",$unMinifiedSanitized);

        //removing inline js
        $unMinifiedSanitized = preg_replace("/([ ]href.*=\".*javascript:.*\")|([ ]href.*='.*javascript:.*')|([ ]href.*=.*javascript:.*)/i","",$unMinifiedSanitized);

                                    
        $sanitizedInput[] = $unMinifiedSanitized;
    }

    if($returnType == "string" && sizeof($sanitizedInput) > 0)
    {
        $returnData = $sanitizedInput[0];
    }
    else
    {
        $returnData = $sanitizedInput;
    }
                                
    return $returnData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this was very usefull for me. try this code.

```
while(($pos = stripos($content,"<script"))!==false){
    $end_pos = stripos($content,"</script>");
    $start = substr($content, 0, $pos);
    $end = substr($content, $end_pos+strlen("</script>"));
    $content = $start.$end;
}
$text = strip_tags($content);
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this:

```
function clear_text($s) {
    $do = true;
    while ($do) {
        $start = stripos($s,'<script');
        $stop = stripos($s,'</script>');
        if ((is_numeric($start))&&(is_numeric($stop))) {
            $s = substr($s,0,$start).substr($s,($stop+strlen('</script>')));
        } else {
            $do = false;
        }
    }
    return trim($s);
}
```