# How do I strip all javascript out of an HTML document using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex, strip

In my email program I use Tidy to clean up the HTML before I send out the emails. A problem is beginning to persist that if I send a mail fetching the html from a url on the web there may exist some javascript in the document.

I want to clean up this html document even more by stripping out all javascript, embedded, referenced and in any form so that the mail exist only of html.

I want to use php's `preg_replace()` to strip out all javascript from a mail and I need some help with the best regex because it's not my strongest point i must confess.

Comment: You can do it in PHP the same way you would do it in any other language. And you cannot use a regex for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $var);
```

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886740/php-remove-javascript).

Comment: +1 clean and easy, I never get though why ppl always use `/` as terminators

Comment: This won't strip out javascript in `javascript:` URLs or `data:` URLs, or in event handlers, or javascript in CSS `expression(...)` or other schemes.   It probably won't handle `<script` with embedded NULs.

Comment: And this will also fail badly on some trivial inputs like `<scrip<script></script>t>alert(1337)</script>`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, The javascript I am getting is of a set format so additional checks is not necessary. I'm getting a book on regular expressions today! Powerful little pieces of code but way over my head at the moment.

Comment: Welcome to the `<img src='road to nowhere' onerror='alert(4311)'>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), passing in the tags you wish to *allow* (whitelist) as the second parameter, but that will not remove inline JS - which might be present in onclick properties and such.

```
echo strip_tags($html, '<p><a><small>');
```

Comment: then on an allowed `<a>` , we may have `<a href="#" onclick="alert('Zombie!')">Click Me!</a>`

Comment: This solution does not remove the possible javascript code that was enclosed by the stripped script tags.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Create a regex to strip javascript from Html](http://regexadvice.com/blogs/dneimke/archive/2004/01/17/200.aspx) article. And [Part 2](http://regexadvice.com/blogs/dneimke/archive/2004/01/17/203.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There's no guarantee with this(as below) but I tried to make my light weight solution because html purifier (http://htmlpurifier.org) is a few huge for my tiny goal.
My goal is to preventing XSS and nothing more so the result for XSS attempts will be a lot of dirty things for this code BUT I think it will be SAFE :

```
<?
//href="javascript:
//style="....expression
//style="....behavior
//<script
//on*="
$str = '
    asd 
    <a STyLE="asd; expression" hRef=" javascript:" onx="asd">asd</a>
    asd
    <code><a href="javascript:">asd</a></code>
    <scr<script></script>ipt ... >asd</script>
    <a style="hey:good boy;" href="javascript:">asd</a>';

function stripteaser($str, $StripHTMLTags = true, $AllowableTags = NULL) {
    $str = explode('<code>', $str);
    $codes = array();
    if (count($str) > 1) {
        foreach ($str as $idx => $val) {
            $val = explode('</code>', $val);
            if (count($val) > 1) {
                $uid = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
                $codes[$uid] = htmlentities(array_shift($val), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $str[$idx] = "##$uid##" . implode('', $val);
            }
        }
    }
    $str = implode('', $str);
    while (stripos($str, '<script') !== false) {
        $str = str_ireplace('<script', '&lt;script', $str);
    }
    $rptjob = function(&$str, $regexp) {
                while (preg_match($regexp, $str, $matches)) {
                    $str = str_ireplace($matches[0], htmlentities($matches[0], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), $str);
                }
            };
    $rptjob($str, '/href[\s\n\t]*=[\s\n\t]*[\"\'][\s\n\t]*(javascript:|data:)/i'); //href = "javascript:
    $rptjob($str, '/style[\s\n\t]*=[\s\n\t]*[\"][^\"]*expression/i'); //style = "...expression
    $rptjob($str, '/style[\s\n\t]*=[\s\n\t]*[\'][^\']*expression/i'); //style = '...expression
    $rptjob($str, '/style[\s\n\t]*=[\s\n\t]*[\"][^\"]*behavior/i'); //style = "...behavior
    $rptjob($str, '/style[\s\n\t]*=[\s\n\t]*[\'][^\']*behavior/i'); //style = '...behavior
    $rptjob($str, '/on\w+[\s\n\t]*=[\s\n\t]*[\"\']/i'); //onasd = "
    if ($StripHTMLTags)
        $str = strip_tags($str, $AllowableTags);
    foreach ($codes as $idx => $code) {
        $str = str_replace("##$idx##", $code, $str);
    }
    return $str;
}

echo stripteaser($str);
exit;
?>
```

:D
Dirty code for this moon at home and ...  However it's not a good job (a lot of while conditions take a few CPU time) but it's better than another huge component like html purifier for my tiny goal.

RESULT WILL BE:

```
asd 
<a STyLE=&quot;asd; expression" hRef=&quot; javascript:" onx=&quot;asd">asd</a>
asd
&lt;a href=&quot;javascript:&quot;&gt;asd&lt;/a&gt;
<scri&lt;script></script>pt ... >asd</script>
<a style="hey:good boy;" href=&quot;javascript:">asd</a>
```

I have no experience to css expressions but I know about behavior using for JS VML in IE for curved corners so can be dangerous.
AND FINALLY THERE IS NO AND NO GUARANTEE.

I hope it can be useful for some friend
 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used this one:

```
//remove js,css,head.....
static function cleanElements($html){

  $search = array (
         "'<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>'si",  //remove js
          "'<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>'si", //remove css 

      "'<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>'si", //remove head
     "'<link[^>]*?>.*?</link>'si", //remove link
     "'<object[^>]*?>.*?</object>'si"
                  ); 
        $replace = array ( 
              "",
                                   "",
              "",
              "",
              ""
                      );                 
  return preg_replace ($search, $replace, $html);
 }
```

http://allenprogram.blogspot.pt/2012/04/php-remove-js-css-head-obj-elements.html

Removes all tags, scripts and styles, except body and html, so after using it, i use strip_tags.