# Saving textarea in the database

Tags: php

I've been searching about this, but I can't find the most important part - what field to use.
I want to save a textarea without allowing any kind of javascript, html or php.
 What functions should I run the posted textarea through before saving it in the database? And what field type should I use for it in the database? It'll be a description, max 1000 chars.

Comment: No HTML, javascript, or PHP. So what -are- you going to use to enter data into?

Comment: Sorry, what I want is not to allow the users to save any JS, HTML or PHP in it. I will use PHP to process the submitted form and save it in the database.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I think he means that he does not want any code within the text area to be stored in the db

Comment: Just for clarity, when you ask "what field to use", do you mean "data type", e.g. `varchar`, `text`, `blob`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, ultranaut. I'm using text currently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways to go around in removing/handling code so that it can be saved in your database.

**Regular Expressions**

One  way (but may be hard and unreliable) is to remove/ detect code using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

For example, the following removes all script tags using php code (Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886740/php-remove-javascript)):

```
$mystring = preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $mystring)
```

**The stip_tags PHP function**

You can also make use of the built in [stip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function which strips HTML and PHP tags from a string. The manual provides several examples, one shown below for your convenience:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

**HTML Purifier**

You can check out [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), which is a common HTML filter PHP library intended to detect and remove dangerous code.

Simple code found on their [Getting Started](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs) Section:

```
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

**In Practice (Safe Output)**

If you are trying to avoid XSS attacks or Injection attacks, cleaning user data is the wrong way to go about it. Removing tags is not a 100 % guarantee for keeping your service safe from these attacks. Therefore, in practice, user data containing code is not usually filtered/ cleaned, but rather *escaped* during output. More specifically, the special characters within the string are escaped, where these characters are based on the syntax of the language. An example of this is making use of PHP's [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function in order to convert special characters to their respective HTML entities. A Code Snippet taken from manual is shown below:

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

For more information about escaping and a very good explanation related to your question, look at this [page](https://www.lazycat.org/php-output-escaping.html). It shows you other forms of output escaping. Also, for a question and answer related to escaping, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).

Furthermore, one more short but **VITAL** point I want to throw at you is that **ANY** data received from a user **CANNOT** be trusted.

**SQL Injection Attacks**

Definition (From [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection))

> A SQL injection attack consists of insertion or "injection" of a SQL
>   query via the input data from the client to the application. A
>   successful SQL injection exploit can read sensitive data from the
>   database, modify database data (Insert/Update/Delete), execute
>   administration operations on the database (such as shutdown the DBMS),
>   recover the content of a given file present on the DBMS file system
>   and in some cases issue commands to the operating system.

**For SQL Injection attacks**: Use prepared statements and parameterized queries when storing information to the database. (Question and Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)) A tutorial of prepared statements using PDO can be found [here](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Prepared-Statement-P550.html).

**Cross-site Scripting (XSS)**

**Definition** (from [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS)):

> Cross-Site Scripting attacks are a type of injection problem, in which
>   malicious scripts are injected into the otherwise benign and trusted
>   web sites. Cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks occur when an attacker
>   uses a web application to send malicious code, generally in the form
>   of a browser side script, to a different end user.

I personally like this image for a better understanding.

[image]

**For XSS attacks**: you should consult this famous [page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), which describes rule by rule on what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:**

It is conventional to use `htmlspecialchars()` to encode text on output, rather than filter the text on input. A `text` field is fine for this purpose.

### What you need to defend against

You are trying to protect yourself from [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS). XSS happens when users can stored HTML control characters on your site. Other users will see this HTML markup, so a malicious user can use your page to redirect people to other sites or steal cookies and so on.

You need to consider this for all of your inputs: this should include any `varchar` or `text` field that can be stored in your database; not just your `textarea`s. I can add malicious content to an `input` field just as easily as I can add it to a `textarea`.

### How do we defend against this?

Let's say that a user claims that their username is:

```
<script src="http://example.com/malicious.js"></script>
```

The simplest way to handle this is to save this into the database "as is". However, whenever you `echo` it on the site, you should filter it through the PHP `htmlspecialchars()` function:

```
echo 'Hi, my name is ' . htmlspecialchars($user->username) . '!';
```

`htmlspecialchars` turns the HTML control characters (`<`, `>`, `&`, `'`, and `"`) into their HTML Entities (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&apos;`, and `&quot;`). This would look like the original character in a browser (i.e.: to normal users), but it would not act like actual HTML markup.

The result is that instead of malicious JavaScript, the user's name would literally look like **<script src="http: //example.com/malicious.js"></script>**.

### Why filter on output? Why not on input?

1 - [OWASP recommends this way](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Output_Encoding_Rules_Summary)

2 - If you forget to protect an input field, and someone figures it out and adds malicious content, you now need to find the malicious content in the database *and* repair the fault code on your site.

3 - If you forget to encode an output field, and someone manages to sneak in malicious input, then you only need to repair the faulty code on your site.

4 - It is possible for users to write usernames that would break the HTML fields used to edit the usernames. If you encode the content *before* you store it in the database, then you need to display it "as is" in the appropriate input fields (let's assume that an admin or the user can change their username later). But, let's suppose that a user found a way to inject malicious code into the database. What if they said that their username is: `" style="display:none;" />`. The input field that would let the administrator change this username now looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" style="display:none;" />" />
                malicious content ->      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, the admins can't fix the problem: the input field has disappeared. But, if you encode the text on output, then all of your input fields will have protection against malicous content. Now, your inputs will look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="&quot; style=&quot;display:none;&quot; /&gt;" />
                     safe content ->      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```