# Disable javascript entry into form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a "HTML editor" for a webpage of mine. At the moment, I only want the editor to allow entry of HTML and CSS elements and *not* Javascript (or Jquery for that matter).

I'm trying to find a way that disables the use of `<script>` or `<script type="text/javascript"> </script>` using PHP. However the current way outputs a messy result!

```
        $content_in_before = str_replace('<script','',$content_in_before);
        $content_in_before = str_replace('script>','',$content_in_before);
```

It's also not very well coded!

Is there a more bulletproof way of coding this, stopping all type of Javascript from being entered into this form? (While still allowing CSS and HTML)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) perhaps?

Comment: [Regular Expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Comment: This will not solve your problem, you can still add javascript via event attributes like `onLoad`, `onClick`, etc. If you really want to make sure no scripts get uploaded, use another language like markdown or use a proven library.

Comment: The use of attributes such as onLoad and onClick do not worry me, as there is a minimal amount of things you can do with them. <script> tags do however, because functions can be written through them , for example.

Comment: Anything you can do in a script tag, you can do in an `onLoad` attribute...

Comment: Are you able to create functions through such an attribute?

Comment: Sure, but what is your concern with functions? They're just containers for the actual code that gets executed.

Comment: I'm not particularly concerned about the use of functions, however the webpage contains AJAX for grabbing data, which I'm afraid by using the HTML editor will allow the user to execute code from within these files. If I shouldn't be concerned,  then I'd allow javascript within this editor.

Comment: no point only trying to remove the easy scripts to find and ignoring more malicious approaches

Comment: @zuc0001 Yes you are. The JavaScript contained within the attributes is automatically executed upon the action. For example, `onLoad` will execute the enclosed JS as soon as it's loaded.

Comment: @zuc0001 As was suggested previously, Markdown would be an exceptional option, but if you want users to be able to use CSS, you'll have to find a solution for that. 

[PHP Markdown Library](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a sanitization library, like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), since just stripping `<script>` tags isn't enough to prevent XSS attacks, since JS can be automatically executed using attributes like `onLoad`, `onMouseOver`, `onUnload`, etc.

To remove tags, and allow some, you can use PHP's [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) function, but it doesn't strip the attributes, hence my recommendation for a HTML sanitization library. If you're able to run it, perhaps one of the best choices is Google's [Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) library, albeit it doesn't work in shared hosting environments since it's written in Java, but it can be hosted on Google's AppEngine.

Also, simple regex solutions aren't always reliable, since even malformed tags can still be parsed. For example, `<script >` wouldn't be caught by simple regex detection of normal script tags unless it's looking for spaces after the tag name. It's possible to check for this, but using an established library would save you time, and would give you the added bonus of a battle-tested library.

Example:
[Script Tags with Spaces producing an alert](http://jsfiddle.net/38ffwf40/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I decided to implement HTML Purifier onto the page and it works like a charm!

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Even though one could write a regex to replace the attributes, but that would require too much work, and regex isn't the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could you a regexplike this

```
echo preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $var);
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1886842/2046700

or as stated us a libary to do this for you such as:
http://htmlpurifier.org/

another possible example:

```
<?php    
   $javascript = '/<script[^>]*?javascript{1}[^>]*?>.*?<\/script>/si'; 
   $noscript = '';    
   $document = file_get_contents('test.html'); 
   echo preg_replace($javascript, $noscript, $document);  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whitelist *tags* you permit, and *attributes* you permit, then remove everything else. You can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) for this.

I wrote this piece of code once but never had anyone else review it

```php
function legal_html($str, $tags='<a><b><br><i><span><table><tbody><tr><td><thead><th><img>', $attribArray=false) {
    if ($attribArray===false) {
        $attribs = array('id','class','src','href','alt');
    } else {
        $attribs = $attribArray;
    }
    $stripped = strip_tags($str,$tags);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML('<div>'.$stripped.'</div>');
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node) {
        for ($i = $node->attributes->length -1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $attrib = $node->attributes->item($i);
            if (!in_array($attrib->name,$attribs)) $node->removeAttributeNode($attrib);
        }
    }
    $stripped = $dom->saveHTML();
    $start = strpos($stripped,'<div>')+5;
    $end = strrpos($stripped,'</div>');
    $stripped = trim(substr($stripped,$start,$end-$start));
    return $stripped;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use something likes this-

```
$content=$_POST['textbox'];

if(strpos($content,'<script>')!==false){
//show error;
}
else{
//proceed with work;
}
```

Comment: Although this is a good idea, I'd prefer the other text to still show; and somehow have the <script> removed by itself.