# Regular expression including two fixed strings and everything between

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not good at all in regex and I'm looking for an expression to get everything between and including either:

```
<script*/> OR 
<script*</script> //asterisk refers to everything between
```

Basically, I want to copy sections from a single  element for print but delete all  tags and everything in between

A single statement that covers both scenarios would be preferable, but two solutions will work just fine

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you're looking to parse some sort of HTML or XML, a parser dedicated for that is probably a better way to go than regexes

Comment: Also, if you're trying to prevent XSS, Basic Regex rarely covers enough to deter any but the most inexperienced attackers. There are a myriad of other attack vectors, including `onLoad` attributes, malformed tags, and more. Please read my answer to this question: [Disable javascript entry into form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576598/disable-javascript-entry-into-form/27576683#27576683)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for both cases:

```
<script.*((/>)|(</script>))
```

Comment: I've tested it, post your sample string which you are trying to parse

Comment: Depending on programming language you can set an option for interpreting . as new line symbol as well. In c# its "RegexOptions.SingleLine"